# How to increment noUiSlider value with Interval function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend, setinterval, nouislider

I am creating a React app, in which I have a NoUiSlider showing a date range. I would like to create a function, that is triggered when a user presses a "play timeline" button, which automatically increments the slider by one step every 1-second ("plays through the dates"). I have not been able to find a feasible solution yet. Any tips much appreciated!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your tags roughly contain the answer to your question; calling `set` on the slider in a `setinterval`.

Comment: Thank you for the answer - Basically, I do not know how to call  `set` inside a class-based component. I'm new to React, coming from `querySelector` makes calling `set` on the component seem very abstract to me! Any clarity would be very helpful.